Strange narrowing conversion error in PPP2 graph.h header
I have recently started studying GUI from PPP2 by Stroustrup, however after installing the latest FLTK I had errors in the headers provided by Stroustrup. Here's the code that I used.
#include "../Simple_window.h"    // get access to our window library
#include "../Graph.h"        
// get access to our graphics library facilities
int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;

        Point tl{ 100,100 };
        // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib
         // to become top left corner of window
        Simple_window win{ tl,600,400,"Canvas" };     // make a simple window
        Graph_lib::Polygon poly;
        poly.add(Point{ 300,200 });
        poly.add(Point{ 350,100 });
        poly.add(Point{ 400,200 });
        poly.set_color(Color::red);
        win.attach(poly);
        win.wait_for_button();
    
}

i had the error:
Error   C2397   conversion from 'Fl_Color' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion shoot_me_in_the_head    C:\Users\abdua\source\repos\Graph.h 159
i was expecting that this code would run seamlessly as its composed by Stroustrup himself, i copied the source code from his book, and the two headers from his website.
i had also corrected two other errors in this header.
any ideas on how to eliminate this error?
the code for the header is a bit lengthy :

#ifndef GRAPH_GUARD
#define GRAPH_GUARD 1

#include "Point.h"
#include<vector>
//#include<string>
//#include<cmath>
#include "fltk.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

namespace Graph_lib {
// defense against ill-behaved Linux macros:
#undef major
#undef minor

struct Color {
    enum Color_type {
        red=FL_RED, blue=FL_BLUE, green=FL_GREEN,
        yellow=FL_YELLOW, white=FL_WHITE, black=FL_BLACK,
        magenta=FL_MAGENTA, cyan=FL_CYAN, dark_red=FL_DARK_RED,
        dark_green=FL_DARK_GREEN, dark_yellow=FL_DARK_YELLOW, dark_blue=FL_DARK_BLUE,
        dark_magenta=FL_DARK_MAGENTA, dark_cyan=FL_DARK_CYAN
    };
    enum Transparency { invisible = 0, visible=255 };

    Color(Color_type cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }
    Color(Color_type cc, Transparency vv) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(vv) { }
    Color(long int cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }
    Color(Transparency vv) :c(Fl_Color()), v(vv) { }

    int as_int() const { return c; }
    char visibility() const { return v; }
    void set_visibility(Transparency vv) { v=vv; }
private:
    unsigned char v;    // 0 or 1 for now
    Fl_Color c;
};

struct Line_style {
    enum Line_style_type {
        solid=FL_SOLID,             // -------
        dash=FL_DASH,               // - - - -
        dot=FL_DOT,                 // ....... 
        dashdot=FL_DASHDOT,         // - . - . 
        dashdotdot=FL_DASHDOTDOT,   // -..-..
    };
    Line_style(Line_style_type ss) :s(ss), w(0) { }
    Line_style(Line_style_type lst, int ww) :s(lst), w(ww) { }
    Line_style(int ss) :s(ss), w(0) { }

    int width() const { return w; }
    int style() const { return s; }
private:
    int s;
    int w;
};

class Font {
public:
    enum Font_type {
        helvetica=FL_HELVETICA,
        helvetica_bold=FL_HELVETICA_BOLD,
        helvetica_italic=FL_HELVETICA_ITALIC,
        helvetica_bold_italic=FL_HELVETICA_BOLD_ITALIC,
        courier=FL_COURIER,
        courier_bold=FL_COURIER_BOLD,
        courier_italic=FL_COURIER_ITALIC,
        courier_bold_italic=FL_COURIER_BOLD_ITALIC,
        times=FL_TIMES,
        times_bold=FL_TIMES_BOLD,
        times_italic=FL_TIMES_ITALIC,
        times_bold_italic=FL_TIMES_BOLD_ITALIC,
        symbol=FL_SYMBOL,
        screen=FL_SCREEN,
        screen_bold=FL_SCREEN_BOLD,
        zapf_dingbats=FL_ZAPF_DINGBATS
    };

    Font(Font_type ff) :f(ff) { }
    Font(int ff) :f(ff) { }

    int as_int() const { return f; }
private:
    int f;
};

template<class T> class Vector_ref {
    vector<T*> v;
    vector<T*> owned;
public:
    Vector_ref() {}

    Vector_ref(T* a, T* b=0, T* c=0, T* d=0)
    {
            if (a) push_back(a);
            if (b) push_back(b);
            if (c) push_back(c);
            if (d) push_back(d);
    }

    ~Vector_ref() { for (int i=0; i<owned.size(); ++i) delete owned[i]; }

    void push_back(T& s) { v.push_back(&s); }
    void push_back(T* p) { v.push_back(p); owned.push_back(p); }

    // ???void erase(???)

    T& operator[](int i) { return *v[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return *v[i]; }
    int size() const { return v.size(); }
};

typedef double Fct(double);

class Shape  {  // deals with color and style, and holds sequence of lines
protected:
    Shape() { }
    Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst);  // add() the Points to this Shape

//  Shape() : lcolor(fl_color()),
//      ls(0),
//      fcolor(Color::invisible) { }
    
    void add(Point p){ points.push_back(p); }
    void set_point(int i, Point p) { points[i] = p; }
public:
    void draw() const;                  // deal with color and draw_lines
protected:
    virtual void draw_lines() const;    // simply draw the appropriate lines
public:
    virtual void move(int dx, int dy);  // move the shape +=dx and +=dy

    void set_color(Color col) { lcolor = col; }
    Color color() const { return lcolor; }

    void set_style(Line_style sty) { ls = sty; }
    Line_style style() const { return ls; }

    void set_fill_color(Color col) { fcolor = col; }
    Color fill_color() const { return fcolor; }

    Point point(int i) const { return points[i]; }
    int number_of_points() const { return int(points.size()); }

    virtual ~Shape() { }
    /*
    struct Window* attached;
    Shape(const Shape& a)
        :attached(a.attached), points(a.points), line_color(a.line_color), ls(a.ls)
    {
        if (a.attached)error("attempt to copy attached shape");
    }
    */
    Shape(const Shape&) = delete;
    Shape& operator=(const Shape&) = delete;
private:
    vector<Point> points;   // not used by all shapes
    Color lcolor {fl_color()};
    Line_style ls {0};
    Color fcolor {Color::invisible};

//  Shape(const Shape&);
//  Shape& operator=(const Shape&);
};

struct Function : Shape {
    // the function parameters are not stored
    Function(Fct f, double r1, double r2, Point orig, int count = 100, double xscale = 25, double yscale = 25);
    //Function(Point orig, Fct f, double r1, double r2, int count, double xscale = 1, double yscale = 1);   
};

struct Fill {
    Fill() :no_fill(true), fcolor(0) { }
    Fill(Color c) :no_fill(false), fcolor(c) { }

    void set_fill_color(Color col) { fcolor = col; }
    Color fill_color() { return fcolor; }
protected:
    bool no_fill;
    Color fcolor;
};

struct Line : Shape {
    Line(Point p1, Point p2) { add(p1); add(p2); }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {

    Rectangle(Point xy, int ww, int hh) :w{ ww }, h{ hh }
    {
        if (h<=0 || w<=0) error("Bad rectangle: non-positive side");
        add(xy);
    }
    Rectangle(Point x, Point y) :w{ y.x - x.x }, h{ y.y - x.y }
    {
        if (h<=0 || w<=0) error("Bad rectangle: first point is not top left");
        add(x);
    }
    void draw_lines() const;

//  void set_fill_color(Color col) { fcolor = col; }
//  Color fill_color() { return fcolor; }

    int height() const { return h; }
    int width() const { return w; }
private:
    int h;          // height
    int w;          // width
//  Color fcolor;   // fill color; 0 means "no fill"
};

bool intersect(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4);


struct Open_polyline : Shape {  // open sequence of lines
    using Shape::Shape;
    void add(Point p) { Shape::add(p); }
    void draw_lines() const;
};

struct Closed_polyline : Open_polyline {    // closed sequence of lines
    using Open_polyline::Open_polyline;
    void draw_lines() const;
    
//  void add(Point p) { Shape::add(p); }
};


struct Polygon : Closed_polyline {  // closed sequence of non-intersecting lines
    using Closed_polyline::Closed_polyline;
    void add(Point p);
    void draw_lines() const;
};

struct Lines : Shape {  // indepentdent lines
    Lines() {}
    Lines(initializer_list<Point> lst) : Shape{lst} { if (lst.size() % 2) error("odd number of points for Lines"); }
    void draw_lines() const;
    void add(Point p1, Point p2) { Shape::add(p1); Shape::add(p2); }
};

struct Text : Shape {
    // the point is the bottom left of the first letter
    Text(Point x, const string& s) : lab{ s } { add(x); }

    void draw_lines() const;

    void set_label(const string& s) { lab = s; }
    string label() const { return lab; }

    void set_font(Font f) { fnt = f; }
    Font font() const { return Font(fnt); }

    void set_font_size(int s) { fnt_sz = s; }
    int font_size() const { return fnt_sz; }
private:
    string lab; // label
    Font fnt{ fl_font() };
    int fnt_sz{ (14<fl_size()) ? fl_size() : 14 };  // at least 14 point
};


struct Axis : Shape {
    // representation left public
    enum Orientation { x, y, z };
    Axis(Orientation d, Point xy, int length, int nummber_of_notches=0, string label = "");

    void draw_lines() const;
    void move(int dx, int dy);

    void set_color(Color c);

    Text label;
    Lines notches;
//  Orientation orin;
//  int notches;
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    Circle(Point p, int rr) // center and radius
    :r{ rr } {
        add(Point{ p.x - r, p.y - r });
    }

    void draw_lines() const;

    Point center() const { return { point(0).x + r, point(0).y + r }; }

    void set_radius(int rr) { r=rr; }
    int radius() const { return r; }
private:
    int r;
};


struct Ellipse : Shape {
    Ellipse(Point p, int ww, int hh)    // center, min, and max distance from center
    :w{ ww }, h{ hh } {
        add(Point{ p.x - ww, p.y - hh });
    }

    void draw_lines() const;

    Point center() const { return{ point(0).x + w, point(0).y + h }; }
    Point focus1() const { return{ center().x + int(sqrt(double(w*w - h*h))), center().y }; }
    Point focus2() const { return{ center().x - int(sqrt(double(w*w - h*h))), center().y }; }
    
    void set_major(int ww) { w=ww; }
    int major() const { return w; }
    void set_minor(int hh) { h=hh; }
    int minor() const { return h; }
private:
    int w;
    int h;
};
/*
struct Mark : Text {
    static const int dw = 4;
    static const int dh = 4;
    Mark(Point xy, char c) : Text(Point(xy.x-dw, xy.y+dh),string(1,c)) {}
};
*/

struct Marked_polyline : Open_polyline {
    Marked_polyline(const string& m) :mark(m) { }
    void draw_lines() const;
private:
    string mark;
};

struct Marks : Marked_polyline {
    Marks(const string& m) :Marked_polyline(m)
    { set_color(Color(Color::invisible)); }
};

struct Mark : Marks {
    Mark(Point xy, char c) : Marks(string(1,c)) {add(xy); }
};

/*

struct Marks : Shape {
    Marks(char m) : mark(string(1,m)) { }
    void add(Point p) { Shape::add(p); }
    void draw_lines() const;
private:
    string mark;
};
*/

struct Bad_image : Fl_Image {
    Bad_image(int h, int w) : Fl_Image(h,w,0) { }
    void draw(int x,int y, int, int, int, int) { draw_empty(x,y); }
};

struct Suffix {
    enum Encoding { none, jpg, gif, bmp };
};

Suffix::Encoding get_encoding(const string& s);

struct Image : Shape {
    Image(Point xy, string s, Suffix::Encoding e = Suffix::none);
    ~Image() { delete p; }
    void draw_lines() const;
    void set_mask(Point xy, int ww, int hh) { w=ww; h=hh; cx=xy.x; cy=xy.y; }
    void move(int dx,int dy) { Shape::move(dx,dy); p->draw(point(0).x,point(0).y); }
private:
    int w,h,cx,cy; // define "masking box" within image relative to position (cx,cy)
    Fl_Image* p;
    Text fn;
};

}
#endif




I have tried to change the color constructor parameter type to long int but still no use, I have also changed it to unsigned, the latter resulted in a cascade of link errors.

Fl_Color is a macro for fltk::Color which is defined as unsigned (https://github.com/fltk/fltk-legacy/blob/c2171d83a31ae533e37bdbb7458c29041c4d62c0/fltk/Color.h#L41) and a narrowing conversion to int takes place then. It's possible that Strtsostrup's example back then worked, but with a different version of FLTK. In any case, your question is missing an [mre] and necessary debugging details.

yeah I know , it's just I don't know how to make it work again

Don't expect anyone to wade through all that code to figure out which line triggered the error. Trim it to the smallest program you can come up with that shows the problem. If the problem is in one of the headers you probably don't need any of that code, just the one #include directive.
